# CiviVolunteer - View Volunteer Roster

Tags: civivolunteer

The View Volunteer Roster for a CiviVolunteer Project indicates it should only be displaying the Assignments for the current day and future days.  However, it lists the assignments which are in the past.  How do we eliminate the past assignments?

In addition, the "Back to Manage Volunteer Projects" button at the bottom of the window does not work.

Drupal - 7.54
CiviCRM - 4.7.17
CiviVolunteer Extention - 4.6-2.2.1

Comment: I had a go at digging out the link from dmaster but at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/manage I get "API permission check failed for VolunteerUtil/getbeneficiaries call; insufficient permission: require edit own volunteer projects". May need raising somewhere - will flag on chat.

Comment: I am doing this as a Administrator and have every permission available on.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have seen this before when the volunteer opportunity has no end date. When creating the opportunity, did you select "Open-Ended" for the "Schedule Type?"

Comment: All the opportunities are "Set Shifts".  They have a date and duration.  There is no place to define and end date, just the start date/time and duration.

Comment: As I recall, the duration is used to calculate the end date after which the assignment should fall off the roster. I suppose I could be wrong about that, and that only opportunities for which an end date is explicitly defined (i.e., not "Set Shifts") are removed from the roster. Whether it is a bug (e.g., bad calculation) or an unimplemented feature, I don't think you'll be able to change the behavior without changing the code.